# Using Different Voltages in a Circuit?

Tags: power, circuit-design

I've been working on an audio amplifier circuit and found the following circuit.
[image]

If my power supply generates +10V, -10V and GND would there be any noticeable change in the basic functionality of the circuit by implementing the voltages I do have accordingly?

Comment: Normally, in schcematcs, +V  is drawn above GND, and -V is drawn below GND.

Comment: whenyoubunchthingstogetheritmakesitreallyhardtounderstandwhatitisthatyoutryingtodo. This is why we put some effort into sentences so that its clear. The same is true for schematics. Follow standard conventions because it makes it MUCH easier for someone to see your circuit and understand.

Comment: your schematic aready uses +10 V, -10 V and GND ... just move the reference point ... and turn your schematic upside down so that it is oriented correctly

Comment: I am using a schematic from online, this is how it was shown in the book. I never thought of making it easier to read and have it follow standards. Thanks for the help, I think I got the information I needed from jsotola! _]And time to start designing my schematics more legibly.. :D_

Comment: @DKNguyen, there is an alternative convention for negative supply circuits like this one to draw them "upside-down" to show the similarity to a positive supply circuit with opposite transistor polarity.

Comment: @ThePhoton I see.

Comment: So there's no way that changing voltages could alter the sound or output? I wouldn't think so, but it's always good to be sure, right?